# How do you add alt text (for accessibility) to images in PowerPoint files created using rmarkdown?

Tags: r-markdown, accessibility

I'm hoping to use rmarkdown to update slides so that future changes can be tracked more easily.  I'd prefer to use the PowerPoint output format, but I need to make sure all images have appropriate alt text (the text that is used by screen readers to describe an image). However, the alt text I'm adding to images is being displayed as a title, and the alt text itself is the url for the image. See example below. Any ideas on how to fix this or other approaches? Thanks.

```
---
title: "Making presentations in R"
author: "author"
date: "3/29/2021"
output: 
  powerpoint_presentation
---

## test slide

:::::::::::::: {.columns}
::: {.column}
* Bullet 1 asdfjadfj aio[jfarja[r f ai[fja[ adiofja[di[  a[ifja[rj 
  + subheader sentence
* Bullet 2
  + subheader sentence
* Bullet 3
  + subheader sentence
:::
::: {.column}
![**Dow Puffin** *Matthew Zalewski / CC BY (https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0)*](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/94/Puffin_Mrkoww.jpg)
:::
::::::::::::::
::: notes
This is a speaker note.

- Use basic Markdown
- like this list
- *and inline formatting*
:::
```

Comment: Sounds like you REALLY don't need to use powerpoint? Please consider using another Rmarkdown slide template, this only requires a web browser! not just powerpoint. This would make it a lot easier to use Rmarkdown and alt text for images. let me know if you would consider not having to use powerpoint, that's the point of Rmarkdown. Death by powerpoint

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm not familiar with *rmarkdown*, the [official documentation for rendering PowerPoint slides](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360004672913-Rendering-PowerPoint-presentations-with-RStudio#images-and-tables) offers a number of options for images, however alt text is not one of them.

```
# image from file
![](file)

# image from web
![](URL)

# linked image
[![](image)](link)

# plain caption
![caption](image)

# linked caption
![[caption](link)](image)
```

It appears that an image caption is as close as you're going to get, and a caption is really not the same thing as alt text. Because it's PowerPoint, that image caption will come in the form of a text box. I wouldn't call this "accessible" as text-boxes are inherently problematic and not a good substitute for alt text:

> *Avoid using Text Boxes as they do not show up in Outline View which makes converting PowerPoint to HTML problematic. If there are more than one Text Box on a slide it may be read out of order by a screen reader.*
>
> https://www.washington.edu/accessibility/documents/creating-accessible-presentations-in-microsoft-powerpoint/